# How do i set a form's elements value with javascript from the parent of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This is what i have tried and is not working and i'm not getting any errors.

```
   <iframe id="paymentFrame" width="600px" height="670px" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src='@Url.Action("ISWForm")'></iframe>


   <script type="text/javascript">

 function sendISWPostData() {

     $("#paymentFrame").load(function () {

         var doc = this.contentDocument;
         var form = doc.getElementById('form1');
         var actionUrl = '@ViewBag.WebPayUrl';
         form.action = actionUrl;
         $(':input[name=product_id]').val('@ViewBag.ProductID');
         $(':input[name=amount]').val('@ViewBag.TransAmount');
         $(':input[name=currency]').val('@ViewBag.TransCurrency');
         $(':input[name=site_redirect_url]').val('@ViewBag.RedirectUrl');
         $(':input[name=txn_ref]').val('@ViewBag.TransRef');
         $(':input[name=pay_item_id]').val('@ViewBag.PayItemID');
         $(':input[name=hash]').val('@ViewBag.Hash');

         form.submit();

         //return true;


     });   //end load
  }  // end send

  $(document).ready(function () {
 sendISWPostData();
 //return true;
 });

 </script>
```

I'v been looking for 2days now and feels its time to ask for help...thanks

EDIT: i'v changed the code to use the right jquery syntax. and i still dont get the form's input. the form is in the page ref'd by the iframe.

Comment: Are the two pages on the same domain?

Comment: You are using wrong jQuerys way to set value. Use `$(':input[name=txn_ref]').val('the values goes here');`

Comment: yes they are same domain

Comment: @Sergio thks av done that...same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `val()` with jQuery object instead of `value` attribute.

*Change*

```
$(':input[name=product_id]').value = '@ViewBag.ProductID';
```

*To*

```
$(':input[name=product_id]').val('@ViewBag.ProductID');
```

*OR* change jQuery object to DOM object

```
$(':input[name=product_id]')[0].value = '@ViewBag.ProductID';
```

**Edit**  Based on comments and updated OP

If you are trying to access the contents of iframe then you probably need to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and your code would be

```
$(this).contents().find(':input[name=product_id]').val('@ViewBag.ProductID');
```

Comment: Tks a lot...i forgot that. was switching between jquery and plain old javascript out of frustration...i'v edited my code and still cant get the input values

Comment: Try using contents to get the contents of frame $(this).contents().find(':input[name=product_id]').val('@ViewBag.ProductID');

Comment: bros you are a life saver...please update your answer so i can accept.thanks